# WHERE containing certain values, with CASE containing additional value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I'm trying to query a table named `DeviceGroups` that contains 2 columns, `MachineID` and `GroupID`. Here's an example

```
    MachineID GroupID
   ------------------
    1          A1
    1          A3
    2          A2
    3          A2
    3          A3
    4          A4
    4          A5
    5          A3
```

I need to show all MachineID's that contain GroupID A1 or A2, with a separate column that will give a Yes/No if that MachineID also contains A3. Here's the expected result:

```
MachineID GroupID ContainsA3?
------------------------------
1         A1      Yes
2         A2      No
3         A2      Yes
```

Notice MachineIDs 4 and 5 are not listed because they does not contain A1 or A2, even though MachineID 5 contains A3. I cannot create a WHERE clause to filter only A1 and A2 because all results will show ContainsA3? as false, and if I include A3 then MachineID 5 will appear with GroupID as NULL which is also not permitted. Any ideas? Here is where I got stuck:

```
SELECT MachineID,
CASE WHEN GroupID = 3 then "Yes" Else "No" END AS [ContainsA3?]
FROM DeviceGroups
```

And here's the result:

```
MachineID ContainsA3?
-----------------
1          No
1          Yes
2          No
3          No
3          Yes
4          No
4          No
5          Yes
```

If I add a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT MachineID,
CASE WHEN GroupID = 3 then "Yes" Else "No" END AS [ContainsA3?]
FROM DeviceGroups
WHERE GroupID = 3

MachineID ContainsA3?
-----------------
1          Yes
3          Yes
5          Yes
```

Comment: What if a machine belongs to groups A1 *and* A2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sub query

```
SELECT groups.MachineID
, ISNULL(
    (SELECT 'Yes' FROM DeviceGroups 
         WHERE MachineID = groups.MachineID AND GroupID = 3)
    , 'No'
) AS [ContainsA3?]
FROM DeviceGroups groups
WHERE groups.GroupID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY groups.MachineID
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
select
    MachineID,
    max(case when GroupID in ('A1', 'A2') then GroupID end) GroupID,
    max(case when GroupID = 'A3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) ContainsA3
from mytable
where GroupID in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')
group by MachineID
having max(case when GroupID in ('A1', 'A2') then 1 end) = 1
```

The idea is to use the `where` clause to filter on groups A1, A2, and A3, aggregate by machine, and use the `having` clause to ensure that either A1 or A2 was seen. The rest is conditional aggregation in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

From what I undertand a subquery will do the job :

```
SELECT MachineID, 
CASE WHEN GroupID in ('A1','A2') 
and 'A3'  in (select GroupID from DeviceGroups as dv 
              where DeviceGroups.MachineID = dv.MachineID) 
              then 'Yes' Else 'No' END AS [ContainsA3?] 
FROM DeviceGroups
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tbl ( 
mID int,
gID varchar(2) )    


insert into #tbl
values
(1, 'A1'),
(1, 'A3'),
(2, 'A2'),
(3, 'A2'),
(3, 'A3'),
(4, 'A4'),
(4, 'A5'),
(5, 'A3')


select a.*, case when b.gID is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as ContainsA3
from #tbl a
left join #tbl b
on b.mID = a.mID
and b.gID = 'A3'
where a.gID in ('A1','A2')



mID  gID    ContainsA3
1    A1     Yes
2    A2     No
3    A2     Yes
```